# where dbus proxy interface located?

Tags: python, interface, dbus

I have some `dbus.proxies.Interface`. And some API documentation for it (in *.txt file).

I need add some new function to this interface, but actually i can't find this interface.
Simple chunk of python code for explaining

```
set_obj = bus.get_object('org.Murphy', path)
rset = dbus.Interface(set_obj, dbus_interface='org.murphy.resourceset')
# print(type(rset)) this printing "<class 'dbus.proxies.Interface'>"
rset.delete()
```

I need make that something like `rset.foo()` work with no error. But i don't understand where I need declare and implement `foo()`

Answer (score 1):

To add something to the API you would add the method into to D-Bus service implementation. In this case you would do it in `src/plugins/plugin-resource-dbus.c` in Murphy source code.

Are you sure you need to add a method to the interface, and not just use the existing interface?